# Is there a surefire way to find a space anomaly?

Tags: no-mans-sky

I chose to be a free explorer at the beginning of my game but stumbled onto a space anomaly after warping to a star system that I'd previously discovered. I made the choice to return to the path of the Atlas, thinking that it would allow me to make Atlas Pass V1's, but immediately after making the choice, talked to Polo and received the blueprint and realized I could have remained a free explorer. I reloaded a previous save and warped to the same star system but could not find the space anomaly.

Is this a bug? Is there a way to find another or do I just have to cross my fingers every time I warp to another system?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Space anomalies are really small (compared to other objects in space, like planets or moons), and unlike the space station which is automatically highlighted when you enter the system, anomalies are not highlighted right away. This makes it really easy to overlook. However, if you use your scanner in the system, it should find the space anomaly for you and display a message ("Space Anomaly Located" or something similar), which then adds a waypoint to show you where in the system it is.

As far as I can tell, there is no way to tell if a system will have an anomaly before warping to it.

Comment: So you think that there actually is a space anomaly somewhere in that system, it just hasn't highlighted it for me yet?

Comment: @Vemonus Yes, that's what I suspect. It's happened to me before, similar to you - I warped to a system and went to a space anomaly, then reloaded a save and re-warped to the same system. I couldn't find the anomaly anomaly again for several minutes until I decided to do a scan of the system to see if there were any landmarks on a nearby planet. The space anomaly then popped up.

Answer (score -2):

It would be too easy to just jump from black hole to black hole! I've been told that you have to spend 2 hours in a star system then the next time you warp you find an anomaly!